# Varnish cache is purged on every order

Tags: cache, varnish, magento2.3.3

Each time I place an order in my Magento 2.3.3 installation all category pages are purged. I found these messages in the debug.log but I can't find what is causing this. Or could this be the default Magento behaviour? Or how can I find what exactly is causing this?

```
[2019-11-23 21:34:51] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"POST","url":"https://website.com/rest/nl/V1/guest-carts/sUS70mJtnIrg0653PcKjxHyhPPY9lzyo/payment-information","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["cat_p","FPC"],"mode":"matchingTag"}} []
[2019-11-23 21:34:51] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"POST","url":"https://website.com/rest/nl/V1/guest-carts/sUS70mJtnIrg0653PcKjxHyhPPY9lzyo/payment-information","invalidateInfo":{"servers":["[object] (Zend\\Uri\\Uri: http://127.0.0.1:32780/)"],"formattedTagsChunk":"cat_p"}} []
```

EDIT: I found out it depends on the product you order. But I have not found out yet why some products purge the category pages.

Answer (score 1):

It was the BannersLite and GDPR/Cookie plugin from Amasty.

- The BannersLite plugin purges all categories on each product save and order.
- The GDPR/Cookie purges the ENTIRE Varnish cache when you click OK on the cookie notification.....

Comment: To chime in on this, Amasty Sorting will also stop any of your pages being cached if set to Index on Schedule for it's indexes. Swissup Checkoutfields also does this on order save.

Comment: Almost all Amasty modules are complete garbage when it comes to Varnish caching. Most modules are clearing important tags or the complete cache all the time.

Answer (score 1):

We have the same issue.

How did you figure, that it was this particular module that was purging the cache?

Comment: First try to find out then exactly the cache is being purged (api call, visit, order etc.) in a controlled environment and then just disable modules one by one to check if this solves the problem.

I first disabled everything and the problem was gone so it was clear it had to be one of the modules.